# Update of JPA Entity with composed PrimaryKey leads to duplicate entry error

Tags: java, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa, primary-key

When I try to store the same entity using the spring JpaRepository multiple times in parallel I get a Duplicate entry for key `PRIMARY`. The TestEntity consists of two values, which change frequently, and the TestEntityId stays the same. The idea is to update the TestEntity based on the EmbeddedId using the save method, because I am not sure if the TestEntity already exist in Database.

If this happens frequently for the same EmbeddedId I get the Duplicate entry error pretty fast. I can also reproduce the behavior in a unit test.

When I run the test I get the exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-2-prov' for key 'PRIMARY'

```java
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TestEntityId testEntityId;
    @Column
    private String value1;
    @Column
    private String value2;
...
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class TestEntityId implements Serializable {
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private String prov;
...
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface TestEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, TestEntityId> {
// Empty
}
```

Testcase

```java
@Test
public void testStoreSameEntryMultipleTimes() {
   LongStream.range(1L, 100L).boxed().parallel()
       .map((i) -> new TestEntityId(1.0, 2.0, "prov"))
       .map((te) -> new TestEntity(te , "value1", "value2"))
       .forEach((e) -> testEntityRepository.save(e));
...
}
```

I already tried to add transactions or different locks on the table as well as other way to declare the composed primary key.

It would be great if you have any idea on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Testing floating-point for equality is *begging* to get catastrophic rounding errors.

Comment: Do you get same result, if you don't walk through stream in parallel?

Comment: No than it is working fine and I have 1 entry in DB after it's done. Unfortunately it's called from parallel running processes later that is where I saw the issue the first time before reproducing it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're creating 100 entities with the same primary key, instead of using the `i` to increment them.

Comment: Yes this is right, I like to create it once and after that it should be updated 99 times. From my point of view the save method is able to create as well as update the entry, am I right ?

Comment: No. You are creating new entities every time. If you want to update an old entity you need to fetch it from the EntityManager, and work on that object.

Comment: Why is this needed ? I know the PK and this one won'T change the isNew method of SimpleJpaRepository will return false because the PK is not null. So the merge function is used which leads to an update based on the PK right ?

Comment: The PK is not null, so merge is called, instead of persist. Now in JPA 2.1 specs 3.2.7.1 it says `If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity instance X'`. You are creating new instances in the example, so it is treated as a new entity.